# installing numpy&scipy on centos 6.4

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, centos, scipy

I am working in a virtual environment and I am having trouble installing numpy and scipy. It is my understanding that I have to full install numpy before going to scipy, but I am having trouble installing numpy.

I used`pip install numpy` and that installed numpy into my python2.7/site-packages/numpy directory, however, I am trying to run `python setup.py install --user` as stated here [numpy build](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/linux.html) and I keep getting the error "this is the wrong file to run". I do not know where to go from here....and I still need to install scipy

Comment: The question is unclear, sounds like pip installed numpy ok on your system but you have trouble with scipy? You should include I/O from your shell commands.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

numpy and scipy come pre-compiled with CentOS, just type:

```
sudo yum install numpy scipy
```

it is always harder to install from source code.